# Show PHP variables on form submit alert box

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I have a form on which I am having submit button. On submit it pops a alert box that informs about the data to be submitted. I want to show php variables on that for information(alert box) but not getting it. I have the code down here and seeking for some solution. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return confirm('You have created a new batch' + <?php echo $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1;?> +'. Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
```

Comment: "but not getting it"? What exactly does that mean? What's the HTML source generated by this?

Comment: It means the php variables are not being displayed.

Comment: Stay calm. I have just asked a question. Don't take it so much . If you have trouble please feel free to move away. Thanks. @ChrisG

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the php car is echoed outside the quotes so it’s identified by JavaScript as a JavaScript variable.

To understand it, think that when requesting the page, the server will generate the php and send the html to the web browser. The web only receives html, css and JavaScript, it doesn’t get any php code, only the results.

So here, your web browser read this JavaScript code :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return confirm('You have created a new batch' + myphpvar +'. Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
```

And it’s not correct because it’s not corresponding to any JavaScript reference into your code.

So you just need to have your php var printed inside the string and it will be transparent to your code :

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return confirm('You have created a new batch <?php echo $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1;?>. Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
```

Will display once proceeded :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return confirm('You have created a new batch myphpvar. Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
```

Comment: myphpvar is text or a php variable. it will be treatred as text.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Updated Code -** 
<?php
    $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1 = "Test Content";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        <button type="submit" name="button">test</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        var phpVarData = '<?php echo $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1; ?>';
        function validateForm()
        {
             var confirmResp = confirm("You have created a new batch "+phpVarData+".Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.");
             if(confirmResp)
             {
                 return true;
             }
             else {
                 return false;
             }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `validateForm()` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Sorry, but this fails. The popup does not appears.

Comment: @Syscall Can this be fixed?

Comment: Code has been updated please check again. Create a test.php and paste the code than run and click on the test button you will see the results.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing a string outside the single quotes. Just remove your `'+` and `+'` :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" 
onsubmit="return confirm('You have created a new batch <?php echo $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1;?>. Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
```

But make sure there is no single in your PHP string.

This simple example works :

```
<?php
$rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1 = date("r");
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action=""
onsubmit="return confirm('You have created a new batch <?php echo $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1;?>. Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried this. But not working. The alert box does not pops up now. And my `$rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1`is a date.

Comment: @Anand Did you have an error in your browser's console?

Comment: console seems unaffected. Nothing there.

Comment: @Anand Check the updated anwser with a simple working example.

Comment: Tried this too mate. No alert box popping

Comment: Yes this worked on a new page. But what could be possibility for this to be ambiguous on my page.

Comment: @Anand How are we supposed to tell without seeing the rest of your code...?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

There is no need for the concatenation, you can just echo the variable inside you string

**Example 1**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" 
onsubmit="return confirm('You have created a new batch <?php echo $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1;?> Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
```

Make sure variable should be a part of your string

This will also work

**Example 2**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action=""
onsubmit="return confirm('You have created a new batch' + '<?php echo $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1;?>' +'. Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
```

**Example 3**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate();">
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>

<script>
    var phpVarData = '<?php echo $rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1; ?>';
    function validate() {
         confirm("You have created a new batch " + phpVarData + ".Click OK to confirm or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try to debug in inspect element and show us the output what you are getting

Comment: The console remains empty. Just not getting any clue .

Comment: dude I'm not talking about the console, do inspect element and check the form output on browse

Comment: Yes the inspect element shows the variable value. Burt whats wrong with this to come in pop-up.

Comment: then what are you getting in popup?

Comment: The pop-up does not appears at all. On submit click the value just submits without showing the pop-up, but in the inspect element the variable shows the value.

Comment: try the third example

Answer (score 0):

$rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1 is returning a value but it is considered as a variable since it is not in the quotes, just add the quotes surrounding the php code. That should work.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return 
confirm('You have created a new batch' + '<?php echo 
$rpp_regn_prescribed_startdate_new1;?>' +'. Click OK to confirm or you can 
ignore by clicking Cancel.');">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST) ;  echo "</pre>";
```

or

```
echo "<script>alert('"; print_r($_POST) echo"');</script>";
```

Your welcome